# cordova websocket plugin showing error code 1006 and angular websocket plugin showing isTrusted true error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Angular websocket plugin is working in the browser. But after generating apk in the mobile it is not working, it is showing error. Cordova websocket plugin also not working, it is showing error code 1006. Can any one help me. I am new to ionic.

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
 var ws = new WebSocket('ws://197.164.1.12:8080/example/2');

 ws.onopen = function () {
    alert('open');
    this.send('hello');       
 };

 ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    alert(event.data);   
    this.close();
 };

 ws.onerror = function (event) {
    alert('error occurred!'+JSON.stringify(event));
 };

 ws.onclose = function (event) {
    alert('onclose code=' + event.code);
 };
 ws.close = function (event) {
    alert('close code=' + JSON.stringify(event));
    alert('onclose code=' + event.code);
 };
}, false);
```

Comment: can u post that error content

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is not allow CORS Origin api access. So you can add the plugin 
[CORS Plugin for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Comment: In browser it is working fine. In mobile it is not working

Comment: check the following line of code are available in config.xml  <access origin="*" />